# Промежуток времени SQL

Tags: c#, mysql

В таблице есть столбик Date.
Какой запрос выдаст промежуток значений времени в БД.
Допустим выдать результаты, которые были созданы в промежуток с 21.10.10 по 21.10.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2010-10-10' AND '2012-10-10';
```

Answer (score 2):

Да, все почти верно, только я добавил бы еще часы-минуты-секунды

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2010-10-21 0:00:00' AND '2012-10-21 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Смотря по чём выбирать, это два разных типа!

Answer (score 1):

```
Select *
from table
where date >="2010-10-10"
and date=<"2012-10-10"
```